# Demerit of declaring static method in AbstractFactory

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

The disadvantage of declaring static method in Factory class, according to Head First Design Pattern - "you can't subclass and change the behavior of getPizza method". getPizza method is used by Factory class to decide which type of object to return. If I understand correctly, my class is

```
    public class PizzaFactory {
        public static Pizza getPizza(String type) {
            if (type.equals("cheese"))
                return new CheesePizza();
            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("thisCrust"))
                return new ThinCrustPizza();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Even though the method is static I can always create a subclass like -

```
public class DelhiPizzaFactory extends PizzaFactory {
    public static Pizza getPizza(String type) {
        if (type.equals("cheese"))
            return new CheesePizza();
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("thisCrust"))
            return new ThinCrustPizza();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can use both the superclass and subclass interchangeably.

```
public class PizzaStore {

    Pizza pizza;

    public void orderPizza(String type) {
        pizza = DelhiPizzaFactory.getPizza(type);
        pizza.prepare();
        pizza.bake();
    }
}
```

So what is the disadvantage?

Comment: It must be `final` as well to stop override

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of use case.
Consider case, that you are using API that has the following method of some global API.

```
public void setPizzaFactory(PizzaFactory factory) {
    this.pizzaFactory=factory;
   // set pizza factory and 
}
```

Normally, you can pass both of your factories as argument to that method, but if our API will use the PizzaFactory you have just set, and call its `getPizza()` method, it will always use `getPizza()` method declared in `PizzaClass` despite the fact that you have probably passed some other derivered class as factory object.

If you would have nonstatic methods in your factory, then you could do something like that

`api.setPizzaFactory(new DoubleCheesePizzaFactory)` where `DoubleCheesePizzaFactory` overrides `getPizza` method to always add extra cheese to every pizza. This way, internal "baking" api will use `getCheese` method version from `DoubleCheesePizzaFactory` insteed of `PizzaFactory.getPizza` version (aka. `super.getPizza`)

So disatvantage is just like that: You cannot change the behaviour (by overridding) of methods that are in `super` class.

Comment: I tried this in eclipse and it is exactly what you said! if i don't want getPizza method to be overridden then I should declare it final. If I just use static, subclasses won't know if their new implementation will be picked up or not. It makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. So in general there is not much of a point to declare methods static final as there is no such need - they are not overriden anyway like nonstatic methods. FYI - the same behaviour you will observe using "overriden" private fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to prevent overriding, you'd need to make your method `final`, ie. like this:

```
public class PizzaFactory {
     public static final Pizza getPizza(String type) {
         [...]
}
```

This way, you can prevent overriding, if this is what you want in this case, although in other cases, yes, allowing overriding by not making it `final` can be useful too.